# How do I open FileMerge.app on Mac OS 10.13+ and Xcode 9+?

Tags: xcode, macos, filemerge

I see FileMerge in the Xcode app bundle:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app
```

I know I can open it on the command line using:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app
```

But there seems like there should be an easier way. How can I tell Spotlight about FileMerge so I can open it with the keyboard? Is there another way to launch it without having to use the command-line?

Answer (score 16):

Symbolic links also work.

% cd /Applications

% ln -s Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/ .

Comment: FWIW this does work for letting me go to /Applications/ and click on it, but doesn't make it show up in Spotlight (at lest not so far, maybe it will change, but usually Spotlight picks up changes to Applications immediately)

Comment: This also happened to me, but then when I tried creating an alias, as another another answer suggests, it started showing the alias and the symbolic link, so later I removed the alias.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way I found was `open -a FileMerge`

Answer (score 8):

Put an alias into the Applications folder. Spotlight and Launchpad will find it.

Comment: Hold command and option while dragging FileMerge.app to /Applications to create an alias without macOS wanting permissions to create the alias in the Xcode app's directory.

Answer (score 7):

On MacOS Catalina, you just need to open spotlight (cmd+space) and type "FileMerge".

Comment: Are you sure? I have a fresh copy of Catalina from a laptop bought Jan 2020 and Xcode is installed, but Spotlight doesn't find FileMerge.

Comment: @jerclarke it finds FileMerge on Mojave too. No need to do anything. Retry after ticking all boxes in spotlight preferences.

Comment: yeah, it is not showing up anymore on spotlight, MacOS 10.15.6

Comment: @Rodrigo Right-click on Xcode and select `Show Package Contents`. You should be able to locate FileMerge this way on macOS Ventura 13.2 at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications`

Answer (score 6):

I had to do `xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` in order to have `opendiff` be accessible (required for SourceTree).

Comment: I came here looking for a way to launch FileMerge from the command line while passing the left and right file paths to it programmatically.  It looks like that is apparently exactly what `opendiff` is (`opendiff <left> <right>`).  I wonder why they went with that name instead of `filemerge` for the command line version?

Comment: Works for me, see also here: https://gist.github.com/kristofferh/2895878

Comment: Alternatively, you can open Xcode, then select "Settings" -> "Locations" and select the command line tools in the "Command Line Tools" selector.